# Prove that a self adjoint and idempotent matrix is a orthogonal projection matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-matrices

$\newcommand{\R}{\operatorname{Ran}} \newcommand{\K}{\operatorname{Ker}}\newcommand{\b}{\mathbf}$

> Prove that a self adjoint and idempotent matrix $P$ is an orthogonal projection matrix.

I was given the following hint:

Consider the decomposition $\b x = \b x_1 + \b x_2$, where $\b x_1 \in \R P$,  and $\b x_2 ⊥ \R P$. Now show that $P \b x_1 =\b x_1$, and $P\b x_2 = \b 0$.

---

I proved the $2$nd condition of the hint as follows.

Since $\b x_2 \in (\R P)^\perp = \K P^* = \K P$, $P \b x_2 = 0$.

I think the first hint is not correct. I think it should be $\b x_1 - P \b x_1 \in \K P = (\R P)^\perp$, which is easy enough to prove. Am I right ?

Comment: The first part is very easy using $P$ is idempotent. If $x$ is in the range of $P$ then $x=Py$ for some $y$. Hence $Px = P^2y = Py = x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $P$ is an orthogonal projection matrix, it is with respect to its column space (range). Let $U$ be the column space of $P$:
$$
U=\{Px:x\in\mathbb{R}^n\}
$$
Take any $u\in U$; then $u=Pv$ for some $v$ and therefore $u=Pv=P^2v=P(Pv)=Pu$.

If $w\in U^\perp$, then $\langle w,u\rangle=0$, for every $u\in U$; it follows that, for every $u\in U$,
$$
\langle Pw,u\rangle=w^TP^Tu=w^TPu=w^Tu=0
$$
so that $Pw\in U^\perp$.

Now write $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ as $x=y+z$, with $y\in U$ and $z\in U^\perp$; then, by definition, $y$ is the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $U$ and
$$
Px=Py+Pz=y+Pz
$$
with $Pz\in U^\perp$, as showed before. Since the decomposition of a vector as sum of a vector in $U$ and a vector in $U^\perp$ is unique, from the fact that $Px\in U$ it follows that $y=Px$ and $Pz=0$.

Therefore the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $U$ is $y=Px$.

Comment: Side question : Proving $\b x_1 - P \b x_1 \in \K P = (\R P)^\perp$ and $P\b x_2 = \b 0$ is suffice, right ?

Comment: @user45914123 It's another way.

Comment: @egreg why is $w^TP^Tu = w^TPu$?

Comment: @egreg but I thought it is the thing we are trying to prove? How could you use it in the proof?

Comment: @ASlowLearner Forget my previous comment: the matrix $P$ is *by assumption* self-adjoint.

Comment: @egreg In the first line of your answer, you assumed P is an orthogonal projection matric?! Shouldn't it be that P is a matrix with respect to an orthonormal basis of V instead?

Comment: @ASlowLearner No, I say, in different words, that “in order for $P$ to be an orthogonal projection matrix, it must project to its column space”. Thus we need to show that a self-adjoint idempotent matrix it is the orthogonal projection to its column space.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p$ be the linear morphism represented in $n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$ dimension. You know that $P^2=P$ then we have $p \circ p=p$ which means $p$ is a projection. That's the first step to it.

Now comes the hint, we need to prove that it is not a simple projection but a projection that satisfies
 $$\text{Ran } P =\left(\text{Ker }P\right)^{\perp}$$

Let $\displaystyle \langle x, y\rangle$ be the scalar product of the vectors $x$ and $y$. 
For $x \in \text{Ran } P$ and $y \in \text{Ker } P$ you know that $p(x)=x$ and $p(y)=0$ so first
$$\displaystyle \langle x, y\rangle=\langle p\left(x\right),y\rangle$$
Then $p$ is self-adjoint then it is the same as
$$\langle x,p\left(y\right)\rangle =\langle x, 0\rangle =0$$
And we proved that $p$ is an orthogonal projection and $P$ is the matrix of $p$ in "ladite"-base.
I hope it helped you !