# Proving a Self-Adjoint Operator is an Orthogonal Projection

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, orthogonality, self-adjoint-operators

I need to prove that a self-adjoint operator $T \in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ is an orthogonal projection if $\sigma(T) = \{0,1\}$. I know this means I have to prove $T$ is idempotent, meaning $T = T^2$ (unless there's an equivalent definition I don't know about). Here's what I know:

1. $T = T^*$.
2. $T$, $I - T$, and $T - T^2$ are not invertible.
3. Since $T$ is self-adjoint and therefore normal, it follows that the above operators are not bounded below.
4. $r(T) = ||T|| = 1$.
5. $\langle T^2x,x \rangle = \langle Tx,Tx \rangle = ||T||^2$.

I've been fiddling with these facts trying to get the pieces to fit together, but they're not clicking. What am I not seeing? I need a hint.

Comment: I'm not sure what your actual question is. Is it "Does $\sigma(T)=\{0,1\}$ and $T=T^*$ imply that $T$ is an orthogonal projection?"

Comment: @Math1000 Well, I know that it does, but that's what I'm trying to prove, yes.

Comment: Okay, so from this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2580848/prove-that-a-self-adjoint-and-idempotent-matrix-is-a-orthogonal-projection-matri you need only show that $T$ is idempotent. Sorry if I am not stating anything you don't already know.

Comment: I had gotten that far, yes. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T$ is selfadjoint and its spectrum is $\{0,1\}$, then by the Spectral Mapping Theorem
$$
\sigma(T-T^2)=\{\lambda-\lambda^2:\ \lambda\in\{0,1\}\}=\{0\}. 
$$
So $T-T^2$ is a selfadjoint operator with spectrum $\{0\}$. Then $$\|T-T^2\|=\operatorname{r}(T-T^2)=0.$$ and so $T-T^2=0$.

Comment: The meaning of the Spectral Mapping Theorem just clicked into place, finally. I was having trouble wrapping my head around it.

Comment: Is there a way to use minimal polynomial to do this?

Comment: There is no minimal polynomial for an arbitrary selfadjoint operator. The question is easy to answer with functional calculus, though.